# CocoaPods. The iOS deployment target IPHONE_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I have a host of CocoaPods that all throwing this warning:

The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99.

anyway to correct these?
Would converting to Swift Packages help, and if so is there a way to tell if a Pod has a swift package?

Thanks all,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the pod file at the end, you can use this to set the minimum os version for each of your pods to a specific version and then run pod install command from terminal. This will change deployment target version.

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
    end
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
        end
    end
end
```